# How to include function in documentation test example?

Tags: testing, rust, documentation, rust-cargo

I am trying to make a simple documentation example but it doesn't compile. I tried:

````rust
/// Given an axis in 3D returns the indices of the 3 basis axis in the order such
/// that the first index represents forward (the input) the next the side and the final
/// the up. i.e. it computes the even permutation of basis index that creates the
/// rotation that aligns the basis with the selected axis.
///
/// # Arguments
///
/// * index an index from 0-2 selecting the forward axis.
///
/// # Examples
///
/// ```
/// use crate::axis_index_to_basis_indices;
/// let x_index = 0;
/// let y_index = 1;
/// let z_index = 2;
/// let (forward, side, up) = axis_index_to_basis_indices(x_index);
/// assert!(forward == x_index);
/// assert!(side == y_index);
/// assert!(up == z_index);
///
/// let (forward, side, up) = axis_index_to_basis_indices(z_index);
/// assert!(forward == z_index);
/// assert!(side == x_index);
/// assert!(up == y_index);
/// ```
fn axis_index_to_basis_indices(index: i32) -> (i32, i32, i32)
{
    match index
    {
        0 => (0, 1, 2),
        1 => (1, 2, 0),
        2 => (2, 0, 1),
        _ => panic!(),
    }
}
````

Which gives:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::axis_index_to_basis_indices`
 --> dual_contouring.rs:107:5
  |
3 | use crate::axis_index_to_basis_indices;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `axis_index_to_basis_indices` in the root

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
Couldn't compile the test.

failures:
    dual_contouring.rs - axis_index_to_basis_indices (line 106)

test result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.02s

error: doctest failed, to rerun pass `--doc`
```

The [official docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/rust-by-example/meta/doc.html) are incomplete in this regard. Reading them one would assume the include statement should be `use doc::name_of_crate` but that also doesn't work.

Comment: The function needs to be marked as `pub`.

Comment: Did you miss the `#![crate_name = "doc"]` suggesting the crate used is named `doc`? Doctests have to use the crate like any other external crate. So instead of `crate` or `doc` you have to use the actual crates name `name_of_crate`.

Comment: Oh I see, you need the macro directive to match the crate name. ty.